# How to close Threads before opening new Threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have problems with Java's Multi-Threading feature, so hopefully somebody can help me....

Here is my problem:

In the  JPanel `ExamplePanel` which is located in the JFrame `ExampleFrame` I've added a ComponentListener which invokes the startPaint()-Method. This method should work in a new Thread. My Problem is that by resizing the window "former" Threads aren't closed, meanwhile new Threads are added....

So is there a way to resize the JPanel and to close at the same time the "old" threads, so that the number of threads is not growing, when I resize the JPanel?

I have tried something with a boolean `exiter`-variable, but it do not seemed to work...

here is the code:

```
    package example;

import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Example2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new ExampleFrame();

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);



            }
        });

    }

}

class ExampleFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ExamplePanel examplePanel = new ExamplePanel();
    private Thread t=null;


    private class ExamplePanel extends JPanel implements ComponentListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            startPaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        }

        private void startPaint() {

            t=new Thread(new Runnable() {


                @Override
                public void run()  {
                    //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    while (true) {
                        //System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());

                    }
                }
            }); 
            t.start();



        }

    }


    public ExampleFrame() {
        examplePanel.addComponentListener((ComponentListener) examplePanel);
        getContentPane().add(examplePanel); 
    }

}
```

Comment: See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Comment: Maybe a little more help?

Comment: It gives you the precise code you need. You want me to copy paste it here?

Comment: The text says that I should write blinker=null if I want to stop the Thread, this means in my case t=null?

Comment: I don't see a `t` in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63657/discussion-between-user3133542-and-user1803551).

Comment: This smells of bad design. Instead of creating threads all over the place, use e.g. a [single-thread executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) then submit a `Runnable` task to it each time - that's what the executors are for. But... `startPaint()`? You're not planning on drawing on Swing components directly from your separate thread, are you... ?

Comment: no in the separate thread I just calculate other things,GUI-Stuff is done from the EDT....

Comment: You forgot to define what `t` is, but yes, your `t` is the `blinker` in the link. I would also give thought to JasonC's suggestion, although it seems to not matter which way you take.

Comment: I have a solution!!!!! just take the t.start in the constructor of the class MovingPoints, so that regardless of the Resizing in the ComponentListener, there will be only ONE more Thread...:-))))))

Comment: And the class `MovingPoints` is?

Comment: sorry ein meant the constructor of the ExcamplePanel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the calculations don't take long don't use an extra Thread.

if you need this extra Thread make sure that it doesn't run forever (no while (true) without returning at some point)

you can always interrupt your running Thread bfore creating the new one

```
if (t != null && t.isAlive()) {
  t.interrupt();
}
```

and check in the while(true) loop if the Thread is interrupted

```
if (t.isInterrupted()) {
  System.out.println("Thread ended");
  return;
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: every Thread needs some memory and it takes a little time to start them. So if you create a lot of Threads this is usually not a good idea.